# Javascript parsing int64

Tags: javascript, integer, parseint

How can I convert a long integer (as a string) to a numerical format in Javascript without javascript rounding it?

```
var ThisInt = '9223372036854775808'
alert(ThisInt+'\r' +parseFloat(ThisInt).toString()+'\r' +parseInt(ThisInt).toString());
```

I need to perform an addition on it before casting it back as a string & would prefer not to have to slice it two if at all possible.

Comment: [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) ... [Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_SAFE_INTEGER)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**All** [Numbers](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-value) in Javascript are 64 bit "double" precision [IEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) floating point.

The largest positive whole number that can therefore be accurately represented is 2^53 - 1.  The remaining bits are reserved for the exponent.

Your number is exactly 1024 times larger than that, so loses 3 decimal digits of precision.  It simply cannot be represented any more accurately.

In ES6 one can use `Number.isSafeInteger( # )` to test a number to see if its within the safe range:

```js
var ThisInt = '9223372036854775808'; 
console.log( Number.isSafeInteger( parseInt( ThisInt ) ) );
```

There is also a [BigInteger](http://silentmatt.com/biginteger/) library available which should be able to help, though, and avoid you having to do all the string and bit twiddling yourself.

**EDIT 2018/12** there's now a native [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) class (and new literal syntax) landed in Chrome and NodeJS.

**EDIT 2023/11** the `BigInt` class has been supported in all mainstream JS engines since late 2020.

Comment: Thank you. He has a lot of useful functions which I can see are going to help me for some time to come. Cheers

Comment: you're welcome!  The fact that all numbers in JS are actually doubles is fundamental to the language, but apparently not well known.

Comment: @Alnitak If the largest positive whole number is 2^53, how is it that parseInt() can return bigger than that?

Comment: @Alex for larger numbers you'll get an approximation, with missing bits in the least significant positions.

Comment: In Firefox Quantum 58.0.2, running `javascript:(alert(Math.pow(2, 53)))` returns `9007199254740992`, and running `javascript:(alert(-Math.pow(2, 53)))` returns `-9007199254740992`. If I add 1 to the max or subtract 1 from the min, it returns those same numbers.

Comment: From functions support perspective, **bn.js** much more than **BigInteger** - actually many packages used in browserify, such as **crypto** are using it.

Answer (score 2):

With a little help from recursion, you can directly increment your decimal string, be it representing a 64 bit number or more...

```
/**
 * Increment a decimal by 1
 *
 * @param {String} n The decimal string
 * @return The incremented value
 */
function increment(n) {
    var lastChar = parseInt(n.charAt(n.length - 1)),
        firstPart = n.substr(0, n.length - 1);

    return lastChar < 9
        ? firstPart + (lastChar + 1)
        : firstPart
            ? increment(firstPart) + "0"
            : "10";
}
```

Comment: @x3ro: Why? It's all in getting used to proper indentation. Terse syntax that's following a convention is often better than verbose code that takes ages to mentally parse. I think you are blindly applying conventional wisdom (that "terse is bad") without considering the usage...

Comment: @Ates Goral: No, not really (to the applying conventional wisdom). I see why it is done like this, however I think that it decreases the readability of your code significantly, and thats why I dislike it. But maybe I'm a bit damaged too, because I had to debug code with like 10 nested ternary operators, and it wasn't that much fun.

Comment: @Ates Goral: Yeah, true. However, imagine you need a quick change in such a piece of code. Probably you would rather add another ternary than rewrite it, wouldn't you? :)

Comment: +1 for a functional suggestion. I don't like needless complexity in general, and this *could* be argued as being that, but that doesn't mean it's a bad solution. It just means that if I don't want to allow it, I'll say so in our coding standards. That is, afterall, what they're for.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with standard Javascript. But as always, there is a nifty little library to help us out, in this case [BigInt.js](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html), which will let you use arbitrary-precision integers.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using the Number class?
`var num = new Number(parseFloat(ThisInt))`

Answer (score -4):

Just use [Number(ThisInt)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_Number.asp) for this instead of Int or float

Comment: -1 Does not work in Chrome: `number("9223372036854775808")` and `NUMBER("9223372036854775808")` both fail.

Comment: @x3ro - Check this article, It says Chrome is also supported - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_Number.asp

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag: Yep, but the way you answered one would suspect Number to be a function rather than an object of which you need to create an instance with `new`

Comment: @x3ro - Hey, no I did not mean to create instance of object tough. Check the article, Number() function can be used directly without having to create instance. This is indeed a global function.

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag: Ah okay, my bad. Anyhow, `new Number()` and `Number()` seem to be identical.