# parseInt rounds incorrectly

Tags: javascript, rounding

I stumbled upon this issue with `parseInt` and I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
console.log(parseInt("16980884512690999"));   // gives 16980884512691000
console.log(parseInt("169808845126909101"));​  // gives 169808845126909100
```

I clearly not hitting any number limits in JavaScript limits 
(`Number.MAX_VALUE = 1.7976931348623157e+308`)

Running Win 7 64 bit if that matters.

What am I overlooking?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/UYDFm/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't confuse Number.MAX_VALUE with maximum *accurate* value. All numbers in javascript are stored as 64 bit floating point, which means you can get high (and low) numbers, but they'll only be accurate to a certain point.

Double floating points (i.e. Javascript's) have 53 bits of significand precision, which means the highest/lowest "certainly accurate" integer in javascript is +/-9007199254740992 (2^53). Numbers above/below that may *turn out* to be accurate (the ones that simply add 0's on the end, because the exponent bits can be used to represent that).

Or, in the words of ECMAScript: "Note that all the positive and negative integers whose magnitude is no greater than 2^53 are representable in the Number type (indeed, the integer 0 has two representations, +0 and −0)."

**Update**

Just to add a bit to the existing question, the ECMAScript spec requires that if an integral Number has less than 22 digits, `.toString()` will output it in standard decimal notation (e.g. `169808845126909100000` as in your example). If it has 22 or more digits, it will be output in normalized scientific notation (e.g. `1698088451269091000000` - an additional 0 - is output as `1.698088451269091e+21`).

Comment: Both answers are right, however this one explains it in length and also explains what my seemingly abnormal output means.

Answer (score 12):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5353473/21336)

> All numbers in Javascript are 64 bit "double" precision IEE754
>   floating point.
>
> The largest positive whole number that can therefore be accurately
>   represented is 2^53. The remaining bits are reserved for the exponent.

2^53 = 9007199254740992

Comment: Yes; also see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"

Comment: So why do I get `169808845126909100` instead of some overflow error or something else? That is bigger than `9007199254740992`

Comment: See my answer. Because `1698088451269091` is below that number, and the 0's on the end are part of the exponent (i.e., it can be written as 1698088451269091 x 10^2). It doesn't overflow, because that's the way floating point arithmetic works. It doesn't care that you're looking for integers.