# javascript parseInt errors with long hex string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to parse a hex string to a decimal number in javascript, but i meet something so weird.

The hex string is `'27a4b0795a7d749c'`, I know the decimal number is `2856602098915439772` checked by python and windows's calc. But the js's parseInt doesn't return right answer.

Here's the test code:

```
var hex = '27a4b0795a7d749c';
console.log(hex);
var num = parseInt(hex, 16);
console.log(num);
var hex2 = num.toString(16);
console.log(hex2);
```

the console display (I am using Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m on Windows 64bits):

[image: result in chrome console]

I test it in IE9, and it get `2856602098915439600` as well. But how does this happened?

Comment: Javascript numbers don't have that much precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/41153) (which cites ECMA specs) the largest Javascript integer is `9007199254740992` - way less than your expected value.

Comment: @lonesomeday points out a probably duplicate question, whose accepted answer goes into depth on how JS can have large, imprecise numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297434/parseint-rounds-incorrectly O, JS!