# overflow on parseInt or not?

Tags: javascript, overflow

I was discussing with some about overflows and specifically about integer overflow in parseInt function, where the parameter was not verified before passing it to the parseInt function which then returns the value. I then gave as input some thing like this 9000000000000000000000000999999999999999999999. I then got an exception saying that there is an "overflow in the second argument". I am saying that there is an integer overflow but he is saying that there is not. that is parsInt just informing me. first I want to know who is right. am I wrong. were could I get the source code from javascript engine so that I could see how the parsing is really done

Comment: Have a look at this question maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353388/javascript-parsing-int64 - I know its not what your asking but maybe the answer there may assist you.

Comment: What browser are you using? Different browsers parse Javascript differently.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: You said it was the second argument. Did you do something like `parseInt(someNumber, "9000000000000000000000000999999999999999999999")?

Comment: I'm not getting the error. I tried `parseInt("100", "9000000000000000000000000999999999999999999999");` and it just gave me 100.

Comment: sorry I think the parameters were actually reversed like parseInt("9000000000000000000000000999999999999999999999",100 ). but I tried it right now and I am also not getting the error maybe there some things I am missing. what I kept in mind was the error and the function. that is why maybe it would be a good idea to check parseint code itself and see how it is handle in the engine, in the absence of the program code