# QT5 - QDataStream - Serialize and Deserialize using javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, serialization, qt5

Sample datastream sample:

`0000000000000001000000002600fffff1a800000000`

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream& stream, const STDataPoint& dataPoint)
{
    stream << dataPoint.id(); //quint64 
    stream << dataPoint.isDescriptor(); //bool
    stream << dataPoint.value(); //QVariant
    return stream;
}
```

Is there a way to Serialize and Deserialize QDataStream using javascript? I'd like to send and receive the serialized data over a websocket to a QT application from an HTML5 platform.

Answer (score 0):

You will find javascript has limitations using 64 bit precision.

[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353388/javascript-parsing-int64)