# Wrong value when parsing a number of type String to Number

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
var x = "10207122232230383";
```

When parsing it to integer i get the same number + 1.

```
var y = parseInt(x, 10);
console.log(y);
```

This prints 1020712223223038**4**.
Why is this happening?

Comment: `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is the max value that you can represent with javascript without "loosing precision". this number is over that limit. see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Comment: From the code above it looks as though you are passing an int and not the original string?

Comment: @OliverRadini yes. fixed this .

Comment: @Hacketo Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @VanderVidi if you don't do math on this number, keep it as string, else could use some biginteger library I guess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353388/javascript-parsing-int64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript any integer which until unless cross [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

that will be precision free.When it crosses this MAX_SAFE_INTEGER then it starts  representing the [doubleprecision](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5) 64-bit format IEEE 754 values as specified in the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic.

To Over Come this You can go with any one of this libraries [BigNum](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber) or [Biginteger](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js).

Answer (score 3):

The number is too large for js to parse as an integer. This is explained well in this post:

[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

From a practical point of view, you can handle large numbers in javascript using a library, for instance https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

There are other libraries available which will help you to achieve the same thing, they are discussed at length here:
https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/issues/45

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? Would appreciate it.

Comment: Dunno but maybe try to explain the problem and someone will give you an upvote as a compensation.

Comment: How about now? Doesn't make sense to me to go into a whole load of detail when the question has been answered well elsewhere.

Comment: My bad - updated the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

That number is too large to be represented as an integer. You will have to use a `BigNumber` library as Javascript does not have a `long` type. You could, for example, use the the `BigInt` library developed by [Michael M](https://github.com/MikeMcl), below I have given an example how to use it.

```js
document.write('Maximum value integer in JavaScript: ' + Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + '<br>')
x = new BigNumber("10207122232230383")
document.write('Your value divided by 1: ' + x.div(1) + '<br>')
document.write('Your value divided by 3: ' + x.div(3) + '<br>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/2.1.0/bignumber.js"></script>
```