# String to JSON parse issue with number conversion

Tags: javascript, json, axios, fetch

Hi Here I am using JavaScript to convert string to Json object,Here below my code

```js
    const json = '{"result":true, "count":42,"groupID": 80000000000000809}';
    const obj = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(obj);
```

result is

```
Object { result: true, count: 42, groupID: 80000000000000820 }
```

but required output is

```
{ result: true, count: 42, groupID: 80000000000000809 }
```

Why the groupID value is changing during the conversion.Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks for your response.
I have found solution for this.

```js
const json = '{"result":true, "count":42,"groupID": 80000000000000000809}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json.replace(/("[^"]*"\s*:\s*)(\d{17,})/g, '$1"$2"'));

console.log(obj);
```

The above code I have used string replace method to replace big-integer into string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript parsing int64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353388/javascript-parsing-int64)

Answer (score 4):

The integer you are trying to parse is too large. JavaScript only supports up to 53-bit integers, so the maximum value for a `Number` type in JavaScript is +/- 9,007,199,254,740,991. Any larger and you'll need to use a `BigInt`. [See here](https://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html) for how to work with large integers in JavaScript.

I would recommend changing `groupID` in your API response to a `string` rather than an `integer`.

If you can't do this, then you could also try using a JSON parsing library that can handle `BigInt` types, e.g. [json-bigint](https://github.com/sidorares/json-bigint).

Answer (score 1):

You can always check `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER()`.  Let's compare this result with the number you're working with:

> 9007199254740991
>
> 80000000000000826

Your number appears to be over the technical maximum that JavaScript supports with integers.  I tested with a few other numbers, they appear to have similar problems.  Documentation...

> The Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER constant represents the maximum safe integer in JavaScript (253 - 1).
>
> For larger integers, consider using BigInt. (Source: [**MDN Web Docs: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

You can always use a string, though, since it is likely that you'll actually be getting this JSON from a web-server, rather than locally defined:

```js
const json = '{"result":true, "count":42,"groupID": "80000000000000809"}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj);
```